# Use the actual LASTROW when setting the getRange(value)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've recorded a MACRO for sorting lines in my sheet.

In the App Scrip there's a specific interval of row but i want this sorting until the real last row of the sheet but i can't do it.

```
function Tripardate() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('4:149').activate()
  .sort([{column: 6, ascending: true}, {column: 7, ascending: true}]);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function Tripardate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow < 4) return;
  var range = sheet.getRange('4:' + lastRow); // or var range = sheet.getRange(4, 1, lastRow - 3, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  range.sort([{ column: 6, ascending: true }, { column: 7, ascending: true }]);
}
```

- If you want to use it until the bottom row of the sheet, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var range = sheet.getRange('4:' + lastRow);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var range = sheet.getRange('4:' + sheet.getMaxRows());
    ```
- If you want to use only the data range, you can also the following script of `range`.

  ```
    var range = sheet.getRange(4, 1, lastRow - 3, sheet.getLastColumn());
  ```

#### References:

- [getLastRow() of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())
- [getMaxRows() of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows)

Comment: PERFECT! Thank for helping me.

Comment: @Gionata Pastorin Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.